# Redirection of subdirectory to totally new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, migration, http-status-code-301

I've got a site merge that's a little confusing.

The old site lived at: oldsite.com/Subdirectory

The new site lives at: newsite.com/

I'm unsure as where to put my .htaccess 301 redirects. Do I put them in the sub-directory of oldsite.com/Subdirectory? Or do I just add them to the root .htaccess for oldsite.com/

I *think* that I could just make this happen in the oldsite.com .htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Subdirectory/(.+)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1
```

I tried that above and it's not working. Thanks for the help!

(Both sites are hosted by Dreamhost, if that matters at all.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

At first I kept the subdirectory and placed an .htaccess file inside it saying:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But then found out in a forum I could just do this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /Subdirectory(.*) http://newsite.com$1
```

Hope that helps anyone else!